# How do I get the "parent version" of a file in a git repo?

Tags: git, branch, branching-and-merging

How can I get the "original" contents of a file that I've altered in my local branch - many times - and merged from master - many times. Note that I'm not looking for the master version of the file, I essentially want the file, minus all of the changes in my local branch, at the point in time where it was last altered from another branch:

```
master   a---b---c---d
          \       \
branch1    e---f---M---g
```

So, while I'm working in `branch1`, I need a quick way to get the contents of `c`. `d` is useless to me (it would create terrible false-positives in the sanity check I'm creating and break my pre-commit hooks.)

This is complicated by the fact that the last merge to the current branch may have been from something other than master - the parent branch and the last branch I merged into `branch1` could be anything.

Answer (score 2):

Your branch labels are on the wrong sides, which (I think) makes the graph pretty misleading.  Remember that Git always starts at an *end* and works *backwards*, so:

```
a---b---c---d   <-- master
 \       \
  e---f---M---g   <-- branch1
```

This emphasizes that to find commits that are on `branch1`, Git will start at `g`, then look at `M`, then look at both `c` and `f`, and `b` and `e`, and `a`.  Commits `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` are all on `master`; commits `a`, `e`, `b`, `f`, `c`, `M`, and `g` (but not `d`) are all on `branch1`.

You'd like to find the version of some file as it appears in `c`, so you simply need to work backwards from the tip of `branch1` until you find a commit that is also reachable by working backwards from `master`.  That commit is the *merge base* of the two branch tips.  (In some complicated cases, it may be one of several; here the picture is murkier and it's not clear which commit you want.  See below.)

The command `git merge-base`, with optional `--all` option, finds a, or all, merge base commit(s).  Using it with `--all` you can be reassured that there is only one such merge base and that you have therefore found commit `c`:

```
git merge-base --all master branch1
```

This emits the hash ID of each merge base commit, which in this case is just commit `c`.  If only one hash ID comes out:

```
git show <hash>:<path>
```

will let you see the contents of that file in that commit.

#### When there are multiple merge bases

You get into this situation by having two or more commits that are reachable from both branches that are the "same distance", as it were, from the two tip commits.  The easiest way to get this is with a criss-cross merge:

```
...--A--B---E--G--H   <-- master
         \ /
          X
         / \
...--C--D---F--I--J   <-- branch1
```

Here, commit `E` was made by doing `git checkout master; git merge branch1` when `master` meant commit `B` and `branch1` meant commit `D`.  Around the same time—just after this point, maybe in a separate Git repository in which `E` does not yet exist—commit `F` was made by doing `git checkout branch1; git merge <hash-of-B>` or similar (e.g., `git merge master` in that separate Git repository).

Now, commits `E` and `F` are the *two* merge bases of branches `master` and `branch1`.  Running:

```
git merge-base --all master branch1
```

will show both hash IDs.  Which commit contains the file you want to inspect?  You'll need some other constraint to figure this out.  One possible constraint—which works as long as whoever makes the merges is disciplined about it—is to use the *first parent* linkage: the first parent of `E` is `B`, while the first parent of `F` is `D`.  So the *second* parent is probably the one you want.  However, if someone has been using `git pull` to make merges, or has done some other tricky things, they may have swapped the first and second parents in some cases, and you might get the wrong commit this way.  It's probably best just to inspect both.

#### A special case: `git diff`

If you don't mind looking at all paths, or are willing to give `git diff` a path name, you can let `git diff` find a merge base for you.  As long as there's only one merge base—which is the usual case—this makes your job easier.<sup>1</sup>  The way `git diff` does this is to take over the three-dot `master...branch1` syntax:

```
git diff master...branch1
```

In this case, `git diff` performs the merge base search, so that it finds commit `c`, then diffs commit `c` against commit `g`—the tip of `branch1`, the second name in the `master...branch1` pair.  **Note that the three dots are required here:** a two-dot `master..branch1` gives a quite different `diff`, comparing commit `d` vs `g`.

Add `-- path` to limit the diff to the file you are curious about.  Git will then only show you the one file.  Of course, this shows you a *diff* of the file; `git show $(git merge-base master branch1):path` shows you the file as it appears in commit `c`.

---

<sup>1</sup>If there are multiple merge bases, `git diff` will pick one at random, more or less ... or misfire and show you a *combined diff*, which is very confusing.  Neither of these is good behavior.  I believe `git diff` should just produce an error here, and stop, instead of doing either of these.